# How to solve this integral involving a Bessel function and an exponential?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I have simplified a problem and now have to calculate the following integral:

$$E(x) = \int_0^R dr r e^{-r^2} J_0(x r c)$$

Here, $J_0$ is the Bessel function of the zeroth order and $c$ is a constant.

I know how to solve this *without* the exponential but not how to solve it *with* the exponential.

Comment: If this is a question about how to solve it with _Wolfram Mathematica software_, please include the relevant code. Otherwise, this belongs to Math.SE.

Comment: Try:`f[a_, R_, M_] := 
 1/2 E^(-(a^2/4)) - 
   Sum[-((2^(-1 - m) (-1 + (-1)^m) (I a)^(-1 + m)
       Gamma[1/4 (-1)^m (-1 + (-1)^m) (1 + m), R^2])/
     Gamma[(1 + m)/2]^2), {m, 0, M}] // N; 
g[a_, R_] := 
 NIntegrate[r*Exp[-r^2] BesselJ[0, a*r], {r, 0, R}]; {f[2, 4, 100], 
 g[2, 4]}` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you re looking for a numerical solution:

Only product `c x` occurs, that's why it's useful to introduce a new variable cx

```
int[cx_?NumericQ, R_?NumericQ] :=NIntegrate[r Exp[-r^2] BesselJ[0, r cx],{r, 0, R}]

Plot3D[int[cx, R], {cx, 0, 5}, {R, 0, 10} ]
```

[image]